# Does Heroic trigger on a static effect?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[War-wing Siren](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWar-wing%20Siren%5d) has the Heroic ability:

> Whenever you cast a spell that targets War-Wing Siren, put a +1/+1 counter on War-Wing Siren.

[Captain Of the Watch](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCaptain%20Of%20the%20Watch%5d) states:

> "Other Soldier creatures you control get +1/+1 and have vigilance."

With Siren in play under my control, I cast Captain Of Watch. The Captain has an effect on Siren: +1/+1 and vigilance.  Does this count as casting a spell that targets Siren?  Should Siren get a +1/+1 counter?

I see "Target" to mean the recipient of some spell or effect.

Answer (score 4):

No, the Siren does not receive a +1/+1 counter. Although your understanding of the word 'Target' makes sense in english, it has a rather specific meaning in Magic.

A creature is only targeted by spells or abilities that actually have the word 'target' on it. For instance, [Giant Growth](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGiant%20Growth%5d). From the [Comprehensive rules](http://media.wizards.com/2016/docs/MagicCompRules_CN2_Update_20160826.pdf):

> 114.1a An instant or sorcery spell is targeted if its spell ability identifies something it will affect by using the phrase “target [something],”

The Siren needs to be identified as that '*target [something]*' in order for Heroic to trigger. On instants and sorceries, this is spelled out; casting an Aura (ie [Unholy Strength](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUnholy%20Strength%5d)) on War-Wing Siren also triggers the Heroic ability, as they have an implicit target:

> 114.1b Aura spells are always targeted.

Casting an equipment would not trigger the ability, as they enter play unattached and not targeting anything.  Their equip-ability is not the same as 'casting a spell', so it doesn't trigger Heroic. The same goes for other activated abilities with a target ([Spikeshot Goblin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpikeshot%20Goblin%5d) does not trigger Heroic, also see [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/18464/do-cards-with-abilities-that-target-trigger-heroic?rq=1)).

To look a little closer at what spells do and do not target the War-Wing Siren:

- [Twiddle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTwiddle%5d) would trigger the Heroic ability.
- [Turnabout](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTurnabout%5d) wouldn't, because the card doesn't target a creature, it targets a player.
- [Call to Glory](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCall%20to%20Glory%5d) would not trigger the Siren's Heroic ability, as it doesn't target anything.

(Thanks to @diego for suggesting these cards)

Comment: I'm not sure why you chose to quote 114.1a over [114.1](https://rules.wizards.com/rulebook.aspx?game=Magic&category=Game+Rules#_ucRuleBookSelector__ucRuleBook_dlRules_ctl271_lblRuleCode), but I'd suggest to use that one instead for being more general and therefore better applicable to an unspecific question, as well as better describing the concept of choosing a target. Choosing an Instant-and-Sorcery-specific rule could lead to the misinterpretation that only those effects would trigger Heroic abilities, while creatures' abilities and other effects are perfectly capable of doing the same.